# Cannot access VM CentOS listen port on the host machine use Hyper-V

Tags: centos, samba, hyper-v

I have installed CentOS7 on the Hyper-V and I build a samba server on the CentOS for easily to shared folders.However, I have failed when I trying to connect and seems like network's problem.

I really have some try attempt to find what wrong I do cause that. I do as following.

1. ping is OK
2. ssh is OK
3. telnet samba port 445,139 is failed
4. service Iptables and Firewall is unload
5. command nc 445,139 is OK
6. internet access is OK

So I have no idea with that, Seem like a firewall problem, I guess maybe Hyper-V has an inner-firewall.Is that correct? appreciate any suggestion